# Give a Shared Mailbox permissions to send to a Distro List 365

Tags: email, office365, exchange, shared-mailbox

I think the answer is no but, hopefully someone has either better knowledge or superior google-fu.

We're trying to allow a shared mailbox in 365 to send to a distribution list.

The list itself is restricted and requires access, however, as it's a shared mailbox I can't see anyway of adding those permissions on 365.

Can do it simply enough as a user just not as a shared mailbox.

Thanks

Comment: Is my reply helpful to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of shared mailbox, a shared mailbox is a type of user mailbox that doesn't have its own username and password. As a result, users can't log into them directly. To access a shared mailbox, users must first be granted Send As or Full Access permissions to the mailbox. Once that's done, users sign into their own mailboxes and then access the shared mailbox by adding it to their Outlook profile.

In another words, only you have the shared mailbox's send as permission that the shared mailbox can send mails to distribution list.